# How to get total content of string?

Tags: c++

I have passed a printf formated string to a function and try to separate the content of that string by using sscanf(). But following is the problem with the use of this function.
i have called the function as follws:

```
int var = -1;
ostringstream ossi;
ossi << "myContent";
std::string detailString = "my first line \n
                            the secon dline content is alos present \n
                             also we are also get s sdjhf sf"
myFunction("What value: %d \n  My content: %s \n Detail Content: %s", var, ossi.str().c_str(),  detailString.c_str());
```

The implementation is as follows:

```
void myFunction(const char * format, ...)
{

    int var;
    char myContent[10000];
    char detailContent[50000];
    if (sscanf(myString, "What value: %d \n My content: %s \n Detail Content: %s", &var, cmyContent, detailContent) == 3)
    {
      std::cout<<" #### "<<std::endl;
      std::cout<<"var value is :"<<var<<std::endl;
      std::cout<<"My content is :"<<myContent<<std::endl;
      std::cout<<"detailContent is :"<<detailContent<<std::endl;
      std::cout<<" #### "<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

with above function im getting out put as follows:

```
var value is : -1
My content is : myContent
detailContent is : my first line
```

instead of getting total content of third argument(i.e detailContent) it gets only first line.
any suggestion to get complete content of string. 
Thansk in advance.

Comment: Your code does not even compile. Please fix that to enable others to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Variable arguments in C and C++ doesn't work the way you seem to think it works. See [this link](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx11b.html) for a tutorial on how to use variable arguments.

Or check out the manual page for `stdarg`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that what you are trying to do is:

```
char buf[1024] = {};
sprintf(buf, "What value: %d \n  My content: %s \n Detail Content: %s", var, ossi.str().c_str(),  detailString.c_str());
myFunction(buf); // not using variable arguments at all
```

Even then the function will probably not do what you want. To enable better answers, please write down what you are trying to achieve.

**Note**: the use of `sprintf` and `sscanf` in C++ is not encouraged as they are insecure.