# Unexpected behaviour while using sprintf() and sscanf() in c++?

Tags: c++, linux

i have formated a string using sprintf() as follows:

```
int wValue = 1;
ostringstream ossi1;
ossi1 << "messageContent";
std::string orinal = "this is la large string \n
                      containin large content separated \n
                      by newline character"

char buff[50000] = {};
    sprintf(buff, "What: %d @ Message: %s @ Detail: %s", wValue, ossi1.str().c_str(), orinal.c_str());
std::string myString(buff);
```

after some operation
 im getting char* as follows:

```
char* varCharPointer = myString.c_str();
```

and i tried to separate that string using sscanf() as follows:

```
int varWhat;
char* strMesg = NULL;
char* strCall = NULL;
if(sscanf(varCharPointer, "What: %d @ Message: %s @ Detail: %s", &varWhat, strMesg, strCall) == 3)
{
        // here tried to print the values of varWhat, strMesg and strCall but
        // im aunable to print/get that value.
}
```

return value of sscanf() must be 3 but it gives 1. Anyone tell me what is the reason for above unexpected behaviour?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Almost same topic created 4 hours back by same user : possible duplicate of [How to get total content of string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118834/how-to-get-total-content-of-string)

Comment: Nawaz topic is same but im getting unexpected result in above scenario. so please help me out from above issue.

Comment: You can not use `scanf` and its likes to get string into unallocated pointers like that. You have to allocate memory for the strings, or define them as empty arrays. The standard library in Linux does have an extension to `scanf` that allocates, if you use the format specifier `%as`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scanf and it's variants don't work that way.  For one, %s can only match strings with no spaces -- so it's certainly not going to work on orinal, and maybe not on ossi1 if "messageContent" is a stand-in for a string with spaces.

It's best to use scanf for extremely simple parsing -- e.g. "%d" to read an integer at the beginning, and almost never for strings, unless they absolutely cannot contain spaces.

Finally, you need to make strMesg and strCall buffers -- scanf doesn't allocate memory.  I'm surprised it didn't immediately crash.

Comment: Thanks Lao Franco for above. what can i use at above scenario? Any idea?

Comment: I would not try to write out text like that if I meant to parse it -- use a more standard format (comma separated values -- or another deliminator, XML, JSON, fixed length fields) -- something designed to be parsed, and that makes sense for your data.  Then use a parser for that format.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to allocate memory for strMesg and strCall, or use char array